# Lanczos termination criteria proof

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I am reading about Lanczos termination criteria from "[Matrix computations](http://math.ecnu.edu.cn/%7Ejypan/Teaching/books/2013%20Matrix%20Computations%204th.pdf)" Theorem 10.1.1. In the end of the proof it is stated that

1. if $r_k \neq 0$ then $q_{k+1} \notin \mathcal{K}(A,q_1, k)$ and $q_{k+1} \in \color{blue}{\texttt{span}\{Aq_k, q_k,q_{k-1}\} \subset \mathcal{K}(A, q_1, k+1)}$. Thus, $\color{blue}{Q_{k+1}^TQ_{k+1}=I}$ and $\color{blue}{\texttt{ran}(Q_{k+1}) = \mathcal{K}(A, q_1, k+1)}$.
2. If $r_k = 0$, then $AQ_k = Q_kT_k$. This way, $\color{blue}{\texttt{ran}(Q_{k}) = \mathcal{K}(A, q_1, k)}$ is invariant for A and so $\color{blue}{k=m=\texttt{rank}(K(A, q_1, n))}$

It is difficult for me to understand the colored parts. Could you please provide some explanations?